# How to update a monster using the D&D4 Monster Builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, tools

I'm new to Monster Builder (part of Adventure Tools) and I'm hoping there is a good way to update pre MM3 monsters to the latest standards (in the errata).

As an example, I'm trying to update the Harpy Screecher, the damage appears quite low for a level 9 controller.  I know I can hand code everything in Monster Builder, but I'm looking for a more systematic approach.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I've been doing for my games is the following:

1. Reset the custom modifiers on the
   attack
2. Change the attack to medium
   (for at-wills, normal scale attacks,
   etc)

As per the suggestion from this [thread](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/25425705/Fixing_Monster_Math_Manually_via_MB) on the WotC boards. It isn't perfect but gets them a lot closer to the newest suggested values.

Comment: That looks good, thanks.  I will give this a shot tonight when I get home.

Comment: This did raise the damage some, but I still bumped it farther to match the current standards.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to quibble with the question. The new standards in monster design are not errata. Whether or not you decide to beef up monster damage is definitely your decision, (and it's perfectly legitimate to want to do that) but the harpy stats aren't "wrong".

To use the exact  examples you've used here:

#### Here's a Harpy Screecher.

[image: A Harpy Screecher]

#### Here's an MM3 level 9 controller.

[image: Meenlock Stalker]

From what you can see, the stats (hp, defenses, to-hit..) are mostly comparable, except that basic attack- which is about 8 (average) from the Harpy and 15 (average) from the Stalker. I think the Stalker has a more powerful encounter power (the Horrid Link ability, vice Acerak's Slave), but otherwise the Harpy's screechy pull and slide powers and the Meenlocks dazing and quasi-dominating powers are comparable.

If you *really* wanted to beef up the Screecher I might add some damage to her basic attack, but it might be even better to give her something like a minor action rechargeable encounter power- perhaps something that chains off of slide or daze, minor action, rechargeable on a 4-6. It doesn't even have to do damage. A fortitude attack that gives a character Vulnerability to Thunder damage or reduced defense against charm attacks.. would be great.