# What are the correct stats for Ice Archon Hailscourge?

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, dnd-insider

There's an inconsistency in *Ice Archon Hailscourge's* stats in different sources:

- In D&D Insider, *Ice Archon Hailscourge* is listed as having slam damage as 3d6+12 Cold damage. It cites multiple sources, though *Dungeon 199* also lists these stats for it.
- In the Monster Manual and the published adventure *Assault on Nightwyrm fortress* (P3) however, its slam damage is listed as 1d6+4 Cold Damage.

Which one of these is correct? I've checked the errata and nothing points to any changes to the monster stats. I'm inclined to go with the original print but the compendium should be the most recent source of information, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The D&D Insider entry is a more recent release, and I'd recommend going with that one.

Monster Manual 3 (released in 2010) marked a new era in how D&D 4e monsters were built; the fundamental formulae for the different monster types were... reformulated. The changes were overall fairly well-received. Among its effects, various roles had increased damage output, and solo monsters were more challenging and no longer as trivial to lock down forever.

I'm having trouble finding a comprehensive summary of what changed, but you can read about it a bit in [What updates should be done to older monsters to bring them in line with MM3 era monsters?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/2998/1204) or in [the first couple of sections of this blog post](https://saveends.wordpress.com/2010/06/25/9-reasons-to-get-the-new-dd-4th-edition-monster-manual-3/)

Dungeon 199 is post-MM3, released in 2012, which means its rebuild of the monster is in the post-MM3 era. D&D Insider is showing the post-MM3 stat block, as you've mentioned.

Assault on Nightwyrm Fortress (released 2009) is pre-MM3, as is the first Monster Manual (shock!). Strictly speaking either build is fine to use — the differentiator of pre-MM3 vs post-MM3 however makes it worthwhile to pick the post-MM3 version.